# DevExpress GridControl, map FieldName to descenendent object's property

Tags: wpf, inheritance, devexpress

Have following code:

```
    public interface ITest
    {
        string St1 { get; }
    }

    public class Test:ITest
    {
        public string St1 { get { return "Interface Property"; } }
        public string St2 { get { return "Descedent Property"; } }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ITest> TestColl = new ObservableCollection<ITest>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            TestColl.Add(new Test());
            TestColl.Add(new Test());
            InitializeComponent();
            gridControl1.DataSource = TestColl;
        }
    }
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="382" Width="600" xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid">
    <Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="gridControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="262">
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="St1" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="St2" />
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1" />
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So everything is ok with St1, but St2 is not displayed. I guess because grid do not determine real run-time  type, and use type declared in collection. Is there a way to make this sample work? Standart WPF DataGrid resolve property names correctlly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have answered your question in our forum at:

[Map FieldName to descenendent object's property](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/102212/347828.aspx#347828)